# How to prevent "Path manipulation" issues in C#, .net core For below statment getting error

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1, path-manipulation

Fority Scan reported "Path Manipulation" security issues in following methods

File.Exist()

File.Create()

File.Delete()

File.OpenRead()

File.OpenWrite()

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

should i ignore the scan report or what would be the correct fix for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask]. It's likely that your question will be closed in its current form, because it's hard to understand. We're not necessarily experts in Fority Scan, so you need to provide details on why it thinks there are security issues with those methods, and how exactly you're using them in a way which might introduce a security issue